# Is it necessary to use private functions in models?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, naming-conventions

I'm making a model in CodeIgniter and I don't want any of the functions to be accessible to the user. For controllers you would do something like:

```
private function _myfunction()
{
    dosomething();
}
```

I know this will also work for models but my question is, is this needed? I don't think users can initiate these functions via the URL. The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to follow best practice but if possible I'd also like to avoid prefixing everything with '_' when I call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not necessary.  It's an unusual situation for a user to have access to a class method through URL, and it's only implemented in codeigniter for controllers.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, and in fact prefixing private objects with "_" is depreciated with the actual use of the "private" and "protected" keywords in PHP 5+.

Comment: While that may be the case for vanilla PHP, I think CodeIgniter still requires it.

Comment: "prefixing private objects with "_" is depreciated" - disagree, it is still useful to prefix protected and private methods / properties with the underscore as it is a convenient code hint when the actual method / property is called. I would even say it's still good practise to do so.

Comment: why it is still useful, it is not required or as important as it was say in the past with PHP4.  Many large-scale projects such as Joomla! are doing away with the "_" prefix, while others such as Zend still require it.

The origin was originally to let developers know what methods and properties are private/protected, but with the "private" and "protected" keywords PHP added in version 5, it is not as important.

Comment: @kinglime , it might have something to do with fact that core of CI is still mostly php4.x codebase.

Comment: If CI is php4 based, then it would make sense and in that case, the "_" prefix would be required

Answer (score 0):

No its not necessary.  To prevent access to the method from the browser, just add an underscore before the method: _method() .  This is Ideal if you want to use/call it as a module(HMVC).